# FOSUser - Create user dump SQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I would like to dump the SQL that will be fired when executing this FOS directive

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create my_user my@mail.net my_pass
```

How can I do that ?

---

Is there an equivalent doctrines `--dump-sql` for FOSUser ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dump the SQL"? MySQL keeps a log of all the SQL statements executed. You could search there for the most recent command executed by the current username/session/etc.

Comment: The think is I don't want the query to be actually fired, simply see the generated SQL as does doctrine with `--dump-sql`

Comment: Yes sorry for the missing info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php app/console fos:user:create --help
```

Output the following

> Usage:  fos:user:create [--super-admin] [--inactive] username email
>   password
>
> Arguments:  username       The username  email          The email 
>   password       The password
>
> Options:  --super-admin  Set the user as super admin  --inactive
>   Set the user as inactive
>
> Help:  The fos:user:create command creates a user:
>
> php app/console fos:user:create matthieu
>
> This interactive shell will ask you for an email and then a password.
>
> You can alternatively specify the email and password as the second
>   and third arguments:
>
> php app/console fos:user:create matthieu matthieu@example.com
>   mypassword
>
> You can create a super admin via the super-admin flag:
>
> php app/console fos:user:create admin --super-admin
>
> You can create an inactive user (will not be able to log in):
>
> php app/console fos:user:create thibault --inactive

I suppose that doesn't exists the command you asking for.

Moreover, it seems to be no trace of it even in `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md` file

Comment: Ok I see. So no idea how we could dump this SQL ? (hacking is accepted :)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY We have to move upward to FOSUserBundle services and so on. Maybe an idea is to insert an "interactive" prompt just before writing user into db. Now I can't help you with this research, but is interesting and if I'll have time, I'll take a look later!